# Cassandra doesn't start in windows with directory being auto falgged as READ-ONLY

Tags: cassandra, datastax

[Please reopen this post]

I am trying to set up Cassandra in my Windows 7 machine, when I run `cassandra -f` command as administrator in command console, I received the following error:

> org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Invalid
>   folder descriptor trying to create log replica
>   I:\Cassandra\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377

So I checked the folder and it is **READ-ONLY**.

I then cleared the **READ-ONLY** and restarted the cassandra server, again it failed with the same reason, I checked the folder's attribute, it is changed to **READ-ONLY** again.

Can anyone enlighten me what is the possible root cause and how to fix it?

[Note]

This READ-ONLY issue was NOT mentioned in another stackoverflow post. So my question should not be considered as duplicated.

Thank you very much.

By the way, does DataStax discontinue their community edition for Windows? I couldn't find it anywhere except for some malicious websites providing trojan embedded download. Here is a malicious site: http:/ /dl.driverpack.io/ (link is removed, please avoid download anything from this site)

[UPDATE]
I followed the suggestion to roll back to 3.11.4, now the error if different:

> ERROR [main] 2019-11-14 13:41:45,123 CassandraDaemon.java:749 - Fatal
>   configuration error
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to bind
>   to address localhost/192.168.2.29:7000

I thought maybe port 7000 is used by some other applications so I modified it to port 6000 in the cassandra.jaml

Same error, difference is the error changed **from 7000 to 6000**

Comment: Try rolling back to Cassandra 3.11.4 and see if that helps.

Comment: My installation was actually downloaded from apache, I could not find the windows version for download

Comment: I only found datastax for download, can you please share a cassandra windows link? Thank you very much.

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't a Windows installer package.  You should be able to just download and expand the 3.11.4 tarball.  It is platform agnostic: http://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/3.11.4/apache-cassandra-3.11.4-bin.tar.gz

Comment: @mdivk Based on your edits, it looks like your issue is actually with Cassandra re-setting the read-only flag on your folder. You should rephrase your question to focus on this aspect (maybe reference the issue marked as duplicate, pointing out the differences), and then I think you'll get more favourable votes for reopening this question.

Comment: Thank you doldt, just rephrased the question's title, can you please remove the [duplicate]?

Comment: @Aaron, the datastax community edition cannot be installed here because there is a probably false positive error prompted by my anti-virus, this is making people so frustrated. but thank you anyway, I decided to go back to Linux.

Comment: Create a new question with the update section and try to fit everything as one. Leaving this one closed.